# ArcGIS Geometric Network splits at junctions after editing route?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, splitting, geometric-network

When I edit a Vertex of route (1) in my geometric Network, the route (2) which first was one route splits up in two routes at the junction. The m-Values from the Initial route are from 0.000 - 255.345. After the split the values are 0.000 - 145.673 and 145.673 to 255.345.
Anyone knows why the route gets split up in a geometric Network? I thought the Network should ensure connectivity?
My Network is build correctly.

[image]

Comment: What does your network represent, rivers? If so then the splitting of route 2 make sense to me as polylines should always connect at nodes (end vertices). It sounds like route 1 is simply intersecting route 2 but NOT at a node, so the geometric network is creating a node to ensure connectivity.

Comment: If your lines are set as SIMPLE EDGE they will split when you connect the end-point of another line to it.  To have it not split the lines would need to be set in the geometric network as a COMPLEX EDGE.  See [Simple and Complex Edges](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/overview-of-editing-geometric-network-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2B09EDFE4A0945D29ED055E59B691102)